# How to set up gulp-typescript to generate one javascript file per typescript file into the same directory?

Tags: typescript, gulp-typescript

I would like to use gulp-typescript module to take care typescript compiling. The current setup I would like to achieve is having one javascript file per typescript file in the same directory. It is the same what VS Typescript module does.

Unfortunately, I did not find anything like this in the documentation. I also searched for this in the google but there is no result.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will look for each `.ts` file in src directory and compile it in the same path as the source

```
gulp.task('scripts' , function(){
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(
        ts({
             "compilerOptions": {
                 "target": "es5",
                 "module": "commonjs",
                 "sourceMap": true
             }
        })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {
    return file.base;
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is sample gulp task that will compile your program in accordance with tsconfig and put js files in the same folder as ts ones:

```
gulp.task('build', 
function() 
{
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});
```

Comment: var ts = require('gulp-typescript');